# Вывод файла, созданого bash'ем на php страницу

Tags: php, bash, linux

Есть файл, который создается командой bash'a `$ script filename`, куда записываются введенные в терминал команды. Мне нужно, чтоб этот файл выводился на php-страничку.
Я сделала:

```
$text=file_get_contents("filename");  
$text=str_replace("\r\n","<br>",$text);  
print $text;
```

мне выдает:
[image]

Здесь лишние символы "00;32ma" и подобные им. Все то, что перед starting interactive shell должно разделяться не пробелами, а переносами строк. Я могу заменить "00;32ma" и другие символы str_replace, но вот как убрать квадратики, не знаю. (

Можно ли добиться читабельного вывода этого файла и как?

**UPD** [файл](http://ifolder.ru/25007708)
**UPD2** примерно [так](http://ifolder.ru/25008430) должно выглядеть (без лишних символов, имеется в виду)

Comment: Выложите куда-нибудь фаил который вы пытаетесь вывести. На глаз все квадратики одинаковые :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для перевода "`\r\n`" в "`<br />`" существует функция [`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.nl2br.php).

Вообще вероятно, что квадратик это символ "`\x1b`" попробуйте вызвать `$text=str_replace("\x1b","",$text);`, так как "00;32ma" - часть последовательности для 
задания цвета текста в консоли.

По поводу

> Все то, что перед starting interactive shell должно разделяться не пробелами, а переносами строк.

Сделайте так:

```
$tempText = exploade("======================================== starting interactive shell session", $text);
$tempText[0] = str_replace(" ", "<br />", $tempText[0]);
$text = implode("======================================== starting interactive shell session", $tempText);
```

Comment: Функция nl2br() решила проблему "все, перед starting interactive shell должно разделяться не пробелами". Спасибо огромное!

А вот с форматированием строки осталась проблема.
Я просто сделала:
<pre><code>  
    $text=str_replace("\x1b","",$text);
    $text=str_replace("]0;test@localhost:~","",$text);
    $text=str_replace("[00;32m","",$text);
    $text=str_replace("[00m","",$text);
    $text=str_replace("[m","",$text);
</code></pre>

Если кто-то подскажет, как это все сократить до одной команды, буду благодарна)

Comment: Вот таким образом можно замену уместить в одну команду:

    $text = preg_replace("/(]0;test@localhost:~)|(\[00;32m)|(\[00m)|(\[m)|[\x1b\x07\x0d]/", "", $text);


P.S. у вас там еще парочка символов не видимых затесалась (`\x07` и `\x0d`), но эта регулярка с ними справится

Comment: Спасибо.
Только тут появляется костыль: если у юзера будет другой юзернейм (не test, а test1, как пример), то вот эта строчка  
<code>$text=str_replace("]0;test@localhost:~","",$text);</code>  
не сработает...
а вписывать всех юзеров в замену строки вручную не очень хочется (

P.S. на обычном выводе консоли ее нет %)

Comment: Хм, тогда можно изменить регулярку следующим образом чтобы подходили все пользователи:

`    $text = preg_replace("/(]0;[^@]+@localhost:~)|(\[00;32m)|(\[00m)|(\[m)|[\x1b\x07\x0d]/", "", $text);`

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Именно то, что мне нужно!

Answer (score 1):

Квадратики могут появляться если у вас файл в кодировке utf-8, а в броузер вы его выводите, например, windows-1251.

Comment: Да кстати попробуй кодировка поменять.Обычно при разных кодировках выдает квадраты.

Comment: там не печатаемый символ, от того и квадратик

Comment: В браузере стоит utf-8)